# Assign output of command to shell variable; however, it returns syntax error instead of correct answer

Tags: bash, shell

I have an input variable $1, and I only want the first four character of $1 and store it to a variable (i.e. rundate). I have the current code below:

```
rundate=$(echo $1 | cut -c1-4)
echo $rundate
```

but when I run my script

```
test.sh 20161234
```

it returns an error message

```
syntax error: `rundate=$' unexpected
```

Could anyone help here? Thank you!

Edit1:
if I just have the following:

```
echo $1 | cut -c1-4
```

I will be able to print it as 2016. However, I want to assign it to a local variable that I can use it later in the script.

Edit2:
Not too sure whether it's old bash or new bash, but if I change the code to

```
rundate='echo $1 | cut -c1-4'
echo $rundate
```

I will get

```
echo $1 | cut -c1-4
```

Comment: old bash? try `rundate=\`echo $1 | cut -c1-4\`` (backquotes)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre. Hi Jean, I just tried it, but it returns echo $1 | cut -c1-5 (a string I guess) instead of the correct answer

Comment: backticks, not single quotes. See the duplicate link anyway.

Comment: If the contents of `$1` is a date stamp in yyyy-mm-dd format then `${1%%-*}` gets you the year part without external processes.  (Really old `sh` does not support the `%%` variant, though, and will require something a bit more complex.  Try `${1%${1#????}}` perhaps then.)